# How to connect Oracle Database Using JSP

Tags: oracle, jsp, connectivity

I want to connect my Oracle database with web page using JSP. But data is not saving into database. if you have any idea or the code have any error please comment and show me the way to correct the the following code. Please this is the project of my final semester. 
The code is as follows. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.driver.*;" %>
<%@page import="oracle.sql.*;" %>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<center>
<h1>Program Start</h1>
FirstName:<input type ="text" name ="firstName" id="firstName"> <br>

LastName:<input type="text" name ="lastname" id="lastname"> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<%  
String username=request.getParameter("username");
String password =request.getParameter("username");

try {


Connection con = null;
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");
Statement st = null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
ResultSet rs =null;
String query = "insert into Test (username, username)values           ('"+username+"','"+password+"')";

ps.executeUpdate(query);

} catch(Exception ex){

} 

%>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: within catch statement try ex.printStackTrace() to see if any exception is occuring.

Comment: `catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
} `

Comment: Never ever use empty catch block. Either print it, as described in above comments, or rethrow it as ServletException

Comment: a lot of Thanks for response but it gives me an error like this:type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to open your server in admin mode,so that it can connect to database,hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

Within the try block I had to create statement for the connection and it appeared PreparedStatement wasn't necessary:

```
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String query = "insert into Test (username, username) values ('" + username + "','" + password + "')";

ps.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

quickly get a close look at you values you have assigned two wrong parameters

first is "String password =request.getParameter("username");" which won't give you an error but data posted will be not that genuine, please change "username to "password"

Second is

```
String query = "insert into Test (username, username)values('"+username+"','"+password+"')";
```

which will be a runtime error hence the database will be waiting for a username and a password but you are supplying it with a username and a username. last try to us this connection string

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr"); with the Class.forName being Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;  
class InsertPrepared{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into Emp values(?,?)");  
stmt.setInt(1,101);//1 specifies the first parameter in the query  
stmt.setString(2,"Ratan");  

int i=stmt.executeUpdate();  
System.out.println(i+" records inserted");  

con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

Comment: can you please detail how your answer improves the previous ones ? code only answers might be flagged as "low quality" and removed even if they are technically correct